# Adding gitignore after multiple commits

Tags: git

I am working in a professional environment for about six weeks now and since the start I have been learning git. There was no version control system what so ever here, so one of my jobs is to change that.

Because every website we use is running on Wordpress, I have been putting complete wordpress installations into git. After a while it got annoying because the websites upload files and obviously those aren't tracked by git.

After finding [this](https://gist.github.com/jdbartlett/444295) I tried it on a completely new website and with minor edits it works perfectly! Now I would really like to use it on all the websites, but I don't know what will happen if I just put the file in the repo's. After reading some, git ignores the ignores for files that are already tracked. So I need to delete the files myself, but that is undoable for a whole Wordpress installation! Is there a way of not losing my past commit information, but still use the new ignore file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git rm --cached <file>` will remove the file from the repo but not from the local file system, follow that with `git commit` and the file stops being tracked due to your new `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Yeah I found that, but I need to remove ALOT of files, is it possible to remove everything but a few folders? Also, if I use that command, does it delete history for that file too? (so the repo becomes smaller)

Comment: Yes you can do the same thing for directories, and no it doesn't remove the history.

Comment: So my best bet is to use it on folder with -R and handpick the left over files?

Comment: Yes if you want to execute the nuclear option.  rm everything, than add back what you want.  at the end of the day until you commit, you will not have any effect, and if you make a mistake, then you can always hard reset to HEAD and start over.

Comment: you could also simply run a script to remove the whole bunch of unwanted files....`find . -type f -name "*.bak" -exec git rm --cached \{\} \;` (assuming your unwanted files end with "*.bak")